# Putting everything with the same power together

Tags: polynomials, factorization, coefficients

I'm doing some computations wich involves a lot of big polynomials, for example:

```
-(x^3/3) + x^6/(36 r) + (x^3 y^2)/(6 r) + y^4/(4 r) - 2 x^4 a[0] + (
 x^7 a[0])/(3 r) + (x^4 y^2 a[0])/r + (x^8 a[0]^2)/r - 
 2 x^3 y a[1] + (x^6 y a[1])/(3 r) + (x^3 y^3 a[1])/r + (
 2 x^7 y a[0] a[1])/r + (x^6 y^2 a[1]^2)/r - 2 x^2 y^2 a[2] + (
 x^5 y^2 a[2])/(3 r) + (x^2 y^4 a[2])/r + (2 x^6 y^2 a[0] a[2])/r + (
 2 x^5 y^3 a[1] a[2])/r + (x^4 y^4 a[2]^2)/r - 2 x y^3 a[3] + (
 x^4 y^3 a[3])/(3 r) + (x y^5 a[3])/r + (2 x^5 y^3 a[0] a[3])/r + (
 2 x^4 y^4 a[1] a[3])/r + (2 x^3 y^5 a[2] a[3])/r + (
 x^2 y^6 a[3]^2)/r - 2 y^4 a[4] + (x^3 y^4 a[4])/(3 r) + (
 y^6 a[4])/r + (2 x^4 y^4 a[0] a[4])/r + (2 x^3 y^5 a[1] a[4])/r + (
 2 x^2 y^6 a[2] a[4])/r + (2 x y^7 a[3] a[4])/r + (y^8 a[4]^2)/r
```

and then I have to analyze when some of the coeficients are zero. This would be much easier if Mathematica would factor out the power of the monomials. I've tried to use Collect, but the problem is that it doesn't factor by powers, it factors everything with "the" power (I hope it makes sense). Any ideas on this matter?

Comment: Edit your question to replace the polynomial with its `InputForm` so that it can be copy and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but look up `CoefficientList[]`, `CoefficientRules[]` and `CoefficientArrays[]`

Comment: "a(0)^2" is wrong syntax. Probably you mean "a[0]^2"

Comment: Have you tried "Factor" on you polynomial?

Comment: @DanielHuber yes, but it only factors out the constant 1/12r

Comment: @MichaelE2 if you look carefully there two terms with the power y^4, and I want to write that as one unique monomial. Let's say a*y^4 + b*y^4 , so what would help me is if that was written like (a+b)*y^4

Comment: Try `expr=...;Expand[expr]//.p_*y^4+q_*y^4->(p+q)*y^4` and see if it successfully combines all your `y^4` terms. PLEASE test that VERY carefully before you even think of depending on it.

Comment: Perhaps `Total@MonomialList[poly, {x, y}]` would be more efficient.